# How to convert Intermediate & Leaf Certs (PEM) to JKS

Tags: openssl, cryptography, keystore, jks

I have the following file `keystore.txt`:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFkDCCA3ig2wIB4gIBPDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQ0FADCBnzELMAkGA1UE5hMCZGUx
DDAKBaNVBAgT...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
IaIGLTCCBBWgAwIBAg9w0BAQsBAjABAjABAjABjFADCBnzELMAkGA1UEBhMCZGUx
DDAKINBgkqhkiGBgNVBAgTA...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is an intermediate cert followed by a leaf cert. How do you convert that to JKS format?

Comment: "I don't see which certificate is which." What does that mean?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Question updated

Comment: The first one looks like the start of a certificate. The second one doesn't. You might want to mention how you created this file. A certificate and a private key are two very different things.

Comment: File was given to me to create a JKS from it. Is there any command to run to identify which is which?

Comment: Ok, well it doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: OK will ask the originator to clarify and will update this question :) Thank you James

Comment: @JamesKPolk I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Typically a certificate chain, which is what you now have, only makes sense in association with a Private Key. "JKS" is a particular keystore format, whose entries match those described by the Java [`KeyStore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) javadocs. See the description for `KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry` in the `KeyStore` docs. You'd already have the private key in the JKS keystore. Thus a typical flow is something like the following:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore myks.jks -alias server1
keytool -certreq -keystore myks.jks -alias server1 -file server1.p10
```

`server1.p10` contains a PKCS#10 certificate request. Included in that is the public key that corresponds to the private key in alias `server1` in the keystore. Now you'd take the file `server1.p10` and supply it to your certificate authority (CA). If all is well they'll return to you a file containing a properly signed leaf certificate and 0 or more intermediate certificates. This is likely to be the file `keystore.txt` you are referring to. (Note that all reputable SSL CAs I am aware of will always include at least 1 intermediate cert along with your leaf cert).

You then import these certificates into the keystore, specifying the alias that corresponds to the correct private key, with the following command.

```
keytool -importcert -keystore myks.jks -alias server1
```

And this completes the transaction. The keystore now contains a private key and associated certificate chain accessible through the alias `server1`.